# batch: storing folderpaths in variables

Tags: variables, batch-file

Win7/64bit/batch/beginner

To sum this up, I'm trying to

- search an/all external drive/s for a certain folder and
- copy it to another location.

I looked up for-loops and the xcopy stuff but I'm completely new to batch scripting so this is what I got so far:

```
@echo off

::I found this to be useful for variables in for-loops
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set odrive=%odrive:~0,2%
set backupcmd=xcopy /S /C /G /D /E /I /R /Y


::this part is meant to find all available drives
for %%i in (D E F G H I J) do if exist %%i: (

::and store the drive name
set target=!target!%%i:\
echo "!target!"
```

---

```
::now I want to find a certain folder and use its filepath
for /d /r "!target!" %%a in (*) do if /i "%%~nxa"=="foldername"

set folderpath=!folderpath!%%a ::I want to use this just like I did earlier
echo "!folderpath!"            ::but it turns out to be empty

::the last step is to use the folderpath for the backupcmd
%backupcmd% "!folderpath!" "%drive%\backedUpFiles"
```

---

```
::reset variables
set "target="
set "folderpath="
)
```

No idea if any of this is actually "good" batch scripting but so far I can follow and understand it. I'm expecting the error to be somewhere between the lines (literally) and maybe it has just to do with how I'm using variables.
The error is something about "invalid drive name".

I hope someone can help me since I'm really done searching code after some days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@echo off    
Setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set searchitem=level 3
set target=%drive%\backedUpFiles
set backupcmd=xcopy /S /C /G /D /E /I /R /Y

set backupcmd=echo

for %%X in (C D E F G H I J) do if exist %%X:\ (
    if exist "%%X:\%searchitem%\" %backupcmd% "%%X:\%searchitem%\" "%target%"
    for /f "delims=" %%D in ('dir /b/s/ad "%%X:\%searchitem%" 2^>nul') do %backupcmd% "%%D" "%target%"
)
```

As examples I've set the foldername to search for to "level 3" to demonstrate foldernames with embedded spaces. In the loop we've got to handle firstlevel subfolders separately (a quirk of `dir`, not listing the foldername but it's content). I found `dir` to be much faster than a `for /R` loop, which I didn't get to run without errors anyway.

Comment: Thanks, this helps a little bit! Are you sure it is working properly? I can only find folders on the first level so far (trying to copy from one USB drive to another).

Comment: Yes, I've tested this with folders on 2 drives. You can delete the `2^>nul` temporarily to see if the DIR command throws errors. Additionally, REM the line `echo off` at the top to see how the commands are executed.

Comment: Note: I crossed out "set backupcmd=echo". This causes the error but if I keep this line the program won't really copy my files.

Comment: Oops, sorry, my fault. I put this in as I didn't want to **really** copy during tests. I thought it was obvious. Sorry for your troubles.

Comment: Don't worry, I really appreciate your help! Its not really working, yet, but I'll have a try. (only works with backup echo on. Otherwise the error still shows up (invalid path)).